# Substract two images

Tags: gimp, transparency

Let's say I have 3 images `A`, `B` and `d` with `B = A + d`. Here, `d` is a semi-transparent image.
If I have `B` and `d`, is there a way to get A?

Example (images from Google Images):

A:

[image: A]

B:

[image: B]

d:

[image: C]

I've tried to follow the instructions [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/27486) but it didn't work.

Comment: Never done this, so I won't answer, but your math as stated is reversible:  B=A+d therefore B-d=A. I *expect* that a uniform transparency value (say 80% opaque; t = .8) can be applied to d *first*, so B=A+(td) and therefore B-(td) = A. Ignoring rounding, the main hang-up here are clamped values at 0 and 255

Comment: Does [this](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/72023/52050) answer your question? I think thats what you're trying to do, right?

Comment: It's exactly what I'm trying to do, but it doesn't work. I'm getting this: [image](http://prntscr.com/berxc6)

Comment: Why do you say it's d/2 ?

Comment: oops meant to say (A+d)/2 because after i subtract d from B i get a darker version of A

Comment: It seems to me your automatically normalizing the image after the addition operation. the ratio is actually closer to 3

Comment: To make B, I just took A and added d as a new layer in GIMP, and exported the result

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41013/discussion-between-joojaa-and-zdimension).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do this you will lose some stuff in rounding errors and dynamic range. just subtract the image from the background. Tough it does not seem like your operation is add. its possibly add plus a channel normalization. But yes i can reverse this by subtracting the mask and re normalizing the levels.

[image]

**Image 1**:B-d

[image]

**Image 2**:B-d + Normalized levels

I lose some color dynamic but that's all. Whether or not that is too much or too little deepens on picture. Could i do it in opposite direction so B-A. i could but the dynamic range is already pretty weak

[image]

**Image 2**: Inverse A at 36% + B

Please note: I am only able to do these operations because i know what the images were and can search them.

Comment: Hum. In my opinion too much info is lost. :oP But I deleted my answer.

Comment: @Rafael deepens on image in the case of this image not much was lost. Anyway the operation most certainly is not just add

Comment: I deleted my answer! What else do you want!? Do not humiliate me more n_n

Comment: @Rafael no at all i just pointed out that for most images this would be terrible yes but this image seems to have so little contrast dynamic that it does not really matter that much. Most images would't survive. I agree with that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. By the way, bonus question: is it possible to do the same thing but with A and B? (get d)